# Arangodb. Using cursor to send back data in Foxx service

Tags: arangodb, foxx

In a foxx service, normally the response is send back using

```
res.send("Whatever");
```

But in the case of my data to send back is huge thus, I want to imitate the behavior of cursor(send in several smaller chunk), how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [Query Cursors](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/HTTP/AqlQueryCursor/QueryResults.html).

If you are using Arangojs, then [here is that documentation](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#cursor-api).

Query all the data:

```
const cursor = await db._query('FOR x IN 1..5 RETURN x');
const result = await cursor.all()
// result is an array containing the entire query result
assert.deepEqual(result, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
assert.equal(cursor.hasNext(), false);
```

Or one by one:

```
// query result list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const val = await cursor.next();
assert.equal(val, 1);
// remaining result list: [2, 3, 4, 5]

const val2 = await cursor.next();
assert.equal(val2, 2);
// remaining result list: [3, 4, 5]
```

For the Foxx end of things, you will need accept and use parameters to control the paging. Using the [LIMIT](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Operations/Limit.html) functionality:

```
router.get('/entries/:skip/:take', function (req, res) {
  const keys = db._query(aql`
    FOR entry IN ${foxxColl}
    LIMIT @skip, @take // ** 
    RETURN entry._key
  `, {'skip': skip, 'take': take});
  res.send(keys);
})
```

** either pass in the skip/take values or calculate them based on a page number.

*EDIT
Foxx endpoints are essentially javascript apps. You can easily use a cursor using the paging method above or the cursor endpoints as [documented](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/HTTP/AqlQueryCursor/AccessingCursors.html). You will need to pass the cursor `ID` and `hasMore` properties to the client so it can request the next batch. The 'batchSize' property sets how many results are returned via cursor.

Comment: So it means that in case of complex traversal that I must use Foxx , there is no support for cursor yet? Thank you anyway, I will wait for a while to confirm this before setting this as accepted answer

Comment: @LoredraL Yes, you can use a cursor via the `/_api/cursor` endpoint. Added some clarification to the answer. Does that help?